# Excel Personal.xlsb saving document Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a macro to see if a cell contains this string if so executes a "save as" command with this set name standard. When I try to run the macro the if statements seem to not work. When I go through step by step it hits the if statements but saves the personal.xlsb instead of the file I'm working on. Here the code I know I have something wrong with it

```
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim answer          As Integer
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "String1" Then
    FPath = "C:\String1"
    FName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
    If Len(FPath & "\" & FName) = 0 Then 
        answer = MsgBox("Do you want to Save File As: " & FName & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Microsoft Excel")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
        End If
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End If
```

I am open to suggestion the most I was is to check if the file contains a string if so verify it does not already exist and if so just save instead of save as.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` >> `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`  In Excel VBA `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook in which the code is running

Comment: Thank you didn't think there was a different but I see it now

Comment: Also be aware that your logic may be a bit off - if there is no file with the name specified in cell A1 (i.e. "String1") existing in the C:\String1 directory, the user will be asked whether they wish to save the file there, thus creating the file C:\String1\String1.xlsx.  But if a file called C:\String1\String1 already exists (which, admittedly, is unlikely as usually files will have an extension), the workbook will be saved back to the location it was opened from, which might be D:\NonString2\Variable3.xlsx.

Comment: @YowE3K my logic was if the the cell = this its part of a form - if a part of the form check if the file exist with the name - if no ask to be saved - if not just save the file but I'm a fairly new to VBA so don't bust my chops too hard :)

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you are using `Len(FPath & "\" & FName) = 0` - that statement will always evaluate to `False` because the `"\"` which is part of the string whose length is being tested will ensure that the length is always at least one character.  I'm used to statements such as `Len(Dir(FPath & "\" & FName)) = 0` (which tests to see whether the file exists) and just automatically read that instead of what was actually coded.  I suspect that what I **thought** it said is what you intended to code.

Comment: @YowE3K would "If Len(fullName) = 0 Then" solve that issue

Comment: Using `If Len(Dir(fullName)) = 0 Then` would test for the existence of a file with the path/filename of `fullname`, so that would be an improvement, but it still leaves you with the issues I mentioned in my first comment.  Does A1 contain a filename (e.g. "xyz.xlsx") or just the base part (e.g. "xyz")?  If it is the full filename, then `Len(Dir(fullName)) = 0` will be OK, but if it is just the base part you will need to use something like `Len(Dir(fullname & ".*")) = 0`.  (That will still leave you with the problem of saving to the original location rather than replacing an existing file.)

Comment: The cell only contains a partial name and I didn't include it in the question but I use Formatfile:=56 for the older version of excel (.xls) so if I say FName =.rng.Text & ".xls" this would include the extension of what to look for - would this work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125025/discussion-between-brett-nelson-and-yowe3k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook where the code resides. Presumably, the code being in the Personal.xlsb, that is why it's saving the XLSB file and not the activeworkbook.

Try this instead:

```
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String
Dim fullName As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim s as String
s = "String1"
With ActiveWorkbook
    Set rng = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    If rng.Value = s Then
        FPath = "C:\" & s
        FName = rng.Text
        fullName = FPath & "\" & FName
        If Len(fullName) = 0 Then 
            If MsgBox("Do you want to Save File As: " & FName & "?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Microsoft Excel") = vbYes Then
                .SaveAs Filename:=fullName
            End If
        Else
            .Save
        End If
    End If
End With
```